I've enabled "Reduce Motion" on my mac. Now I want to get rid of the slow fade-in when I hit `command + tab`. Is there a way to achieve this?
Essentially I really dislike the slow behavior of MacOS when command + tab. It's a bit better now that I've enabled "Reduce Motion", but I wanted to completely get rid of the fade in animation. Is this possible?
